# inetmib1.dll does not export SnmpExtensionClose() and other "advanced" SnmpExtension methods

Tags: c++, windows, dll, snmp, dllimport

I use `inetmib1.dll` as SNMP Extension agent. But unfortunately there is no hint for
[SnmpExtensionClose on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378019(v=vs.85).aspx) which states what additional dll I have to import resp. load when I want to use `SnmpExtensionClose()` to let the extension dll deallocate resources (e.g. handle from `SnmpExtensionInit()` - In addition Intel Inspector tells me that there is a memory leak when only using `SnmpExtensionInit()` but no `SnmpExtensionClose()`).

Furthermore `inetmib1.dll` does not export other *advanced* extension agent methods like `SnmpExtensionQueryEx()` or `SnmpExtensionMonitor()`. Which standard Windows dll exports all those SnmpExtension methods from MSDN completely?

Comment: It's not very clear for me what the questions are. Anyway, copy/paste from [\[MSDN\]: SnmpExtensionQueryEx callback function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378022(v=vs.85).aspx): _The SNMP service does not call the `SnmpExtensionQuery` function if the extension agent exports the `SnmpExtensionQueryEx` function_. On the _PC_ that I currently am (_XP_), _inetmib1.dll_ doesn't export it. Could it be that you need to define it yourself? I have to check on newer _Win_ versions (but I doubt I'll find smth, since _Windows Remote Management_ should be used in that case).

Comment: Yes, on _W10_ the function isn't exported either.